# How can I adjust or replace many colours in an image with a new swatch of colours, without causing ugly edges?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, swatches, repurposing

I'm having difficulty replacing the colors in an existing image with colors from a new swatch of colors. I've tried the following :

- Magic wand and fill
- Color replacement tool
- Image -> Adjustments -> Replace color

The latter just wouldn't let me select the color I wanted to replace with I had to fiddle with hue/saturation/lightness. I have about 100 of these images to change to using a different swatch so I need a quick method.

Here's an example image I need to change the colors for:

[image: image that needs to change]

Here's the new swatch showing which colors should go where:

[image: image that needs to change]

This is the best result I can get:

[image: image that needs to change]

Awful. If anybody can forgive my poor Photoshop skills and show me a good way to do this I'd be very grateful thanks.

**How can I replace multiple colours in an image with a new swatch of colours, in a systematic way that I can repeat for a batch of ~100 more images?**

**UPDATE**: Here's my compromise using simple hue/saturation adjustments

[image: image that needs to change]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use a `Gradient Map` as an adjustment layer. You can easily create your gradient by sampling your color key in another open window:

[image: selecting tones using the eyedropper tool]

It also helps to paint samples of your new tones on a new layer above your adjustment map.

[image: gif showing tones painted in place on a new layer above original and mapped layers]

In this case, that should be all you need. If you have an image where a color transition would contain inappropriate tones after being remapped, you may need to mask an remap those areas separately.

[image: output]

Comment: Thanks a lot Alex I learned something new. I really tried using the gradient map but the end result I got wasn't good enough. Maybe in the hands of an expert it'd be perfect... In the end I've compromised and used simple hue/saturation adjustments. At least the new graphics all fit together visually albeit not exactly how I hoped.

Comment: I've added an image showing my compromise. The colours are similar but not as dark. Good enough for now.

Comment: I think what I really need is a gradient map that somehow maps hue and luminosity to other colors, not just luminosity.

Comment: You're right that gradient map only maps to the luminosity of the input pixels, but you can always use `channel-mixer`, `calculations`, `equalize`, etc to remap/adjust the input.

Comment: You're definitely a pro! I'll look into these things cheers.

Comment: Just seen your great update with the animation. Proof it can be done thanks, will be working on this all day.

Comment: This is working for me and I'm bulk updating images using actions, it's great!

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't really answer your question, it's just a work-around since your image has most of the same colors.

made a new layer above the original,

Filled it with your third swatch color,

set the new layer to Multiply,

Looks decent, except for the highlight color — so I used Select Color Range to grab the highlight color as a selection, made an Adjustment Layer to lighten just that area a little.

Here it is:

[image]

Here's the Layers:

[image]

Comment: You're welcome. Hope it helps.